# WebXR typescript support

Tags: typescript, webxr

I want to experiment with webxr and have setup a typescript project. According to [WebXR](https://www.w3.org/TR/webxr/#navigator-xr-attribute)

I should do the following:

```
const supported = await navigator.xr.isSessionSupported('immersive-vr');
```

With my typescript setup `navigator.xr` is displayed as error.
[image]
[image]

I wonder how to setup typescript for `webxr`. My `tsconfig` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "esNext",
        "target": "es6",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "./node_modules"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [add definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#what-are-declaration-files-and-how-do-i-get-them) for WebXR, [such as these ones.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/webxr) Something like running: `npm install --save-dev @types/webxr` and then importing the types:

```
import type { Navigator } from 'webxr';
```

Related:

- [Using WebXR Types](https://robrohan.com/2020/10/16/using-webxr-types.html)
- [The definition source](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/webxr/index.d.ts)

Comment: Awesome, I just needed to install the package, the types were added to the global scope.

Answer (score 3):

Install typings for `webxr` with `npm i -D @types/webxr` in your command line.

Then import XRSystem in your ts file with `import type { XRSystem } from 'webxr';` (Take care about the `type` word in the import).

Then call xr with:

```
const xr = (navigator as any)?.xr as XRSystem;
xr.requestSession('immersive-vr', {optionalFeatures: ['hand-tracking']})
```